# I have an Pavilion TS 17-g199nr, running dual boot with windows 10 (ugh) and Ubuntu 14.04(running on live usbdrive)

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet, realtek

I have tried to install Mint 17.2, Mint 18, and Ubuntu 14.04 from live cd/usb drives.  None of them can see wifi.  I have tried to identify the correct card. The following is my output of the terminal

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** `sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:94100000-94101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 94:57:a5:db:3e:7e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:144 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94004000-94004fff memory:94000000-94003fff
```

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** `lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %`

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80a5
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** `sudo ls /sys/class/net`

```
eth0  lo
```

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon wicd-cli wicd-curses`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-firmware-nonfree
E: Unable to locate package wicd
E: Unable to locate package wicd-gtk
E: Unable to locate package wicd-daemon
E: Unable to locate package wicd-cli
E: Unable to locate package wicd-curses
```

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:57:a5:db:3e:7e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9657:a5ff:fedb:3e7e/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2600:100e:b004:342e:9657:a5ff:fedb:3e7e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2600:100e:b004:342e:2812:2a3d:1d3d:4e6/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8039 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6987958 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:884067 (884.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:125921 (125.9 KB)  TX bytes:125921 (125.9 KB)
```

The network controller appears to be Intel but not identified as to type. The Ethernet is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. `RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)`.  I am presently connected to the internet via ethernet.  I would love to get my wifi back.  It works great under Window 10 but I really don't like Windows.  Still trying to learn Ubuntu/linux

Comment: Can you boot into `Windows 10 (ugh)` and see what wifi driver is in use there and then `Edit` your question with this information? It's possible the wifi card is `blacklisted` in Ubuntu in which case we need to find out why and what workaround is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try blacklisting acer-wmi, or acer-wireless. I have a Pavilion 13 x360 and blacklisting these worked.

My WiFi card is an Intel AC-3165.

Run

> lsmod | grep iwl

post them here.